# cannot use the label in the pivot as there is a space

Tags: spreadsheet

I have pivot created from the master data. In the same pivot when I try to apply the calculative field, ( I have the column name with space), its throwing the formula parse error.

Steps tried to resolved.

1. used single quotes.
2. Tried the automatic formating for the labels and the values.

My data looks like below.

The pivot consists of the following columns name.

assignee_name, source, count of id, sum of res met.

So now I want to added a calcualtive field as follows:

= 'sum of res met'/'count of id'

this is throwing error.

Answer (score -1):

When dealing with pivot tables in Excel or similar spreadsheet programs and you're trying to create a calculated field, especially with column names that include spaces, there are a few nuances to keep in mind. Here's how you can address the issue you're facing:

#### Issue:

Formula parse error when using column names with spaces in a calculated field within a pivot table.

#### Steps to Resolve:

1. **Use Square Brackets for Field Names with Spaces**:
   Instead of single quotes, try using square brackets around field names that contain spaces. Your formula should look like this:

   ```
   = [sum of res met] / [count of id]
   ```

   This syntax is typically used in pivot tables to reference field names that include spaces.
2. **Check for Exact Field Names**:
   Ensure that the names inside the brackets exactly match the field names in your pivot table, including case sensitivity and spacing.
3. **Validate Data Types**:
   Make sure that the fields you are using in the calculation are numerical. For instance, 'sum of res met' and 'count of id' should be fields containing numerical values.
4. **Check for Hidden Characters**:
   Sometimes, data copied from other sources might include hidden characters or extra spaces. Verify that the field names don't have any leading, trailing, or hidden characters.
5. **Recreate the Pivot Table**:
   If the problem persists, try recreating the pivot table from scratch. Occasionally, pivot tables can behave unpredictably, especially if there have been many changes to the structure or data.
6. **Consult Documentation or Help Resources**:
   If you're using a specific spreadsheet software (like Microsoft Excel or Google Sheets), refer to the official documentation for pivot tables and calculated fields, as there might be software-specific nuances.

#### Example:

Here's how the calculated field formula should look:

```
= [sum of res met] / [count of id]
```

This formula divides the sum of results met by the count of IDs, assuming both fields are numerical and correctly named in your pivot table.

Remember, the exact syntax can vary slightly depending on the spreadsheet software you're using, so it's always good to refer to the specific guidelines or help resources for the software.